# Same zone calls in Spring-cloud eureka

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to run some apps in two different zones : office and shahbour

based on my reading if i set `preferSameZoneEureka` to `true` then applications within same zone should always talk together but in my case it is doing round robbin . Below is my application.yml that is common to all applications

```
eureka:
  client:
    preferSameZoneEureka: true
    region: lebanon
    serviceUrl:
      office: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
      shahbour: http://192.168.15.202:8761/eureka/
    availabilityZones:
      lebanon: office
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}}
      zone: office
hystrix:
  command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000

---
spring:
  profiles: shahbour
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: shahbour
  client:
    availabilityZones:
      lebanon: shahbour
```

My understanding is that all application that have profile `shahbour`
active should talk to each other unless it is not found they fall back to applications in zone `office`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found out that i need two eureka to be able to accomplish the above , one in each zone

below is my eureka configuration

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}
---
spring:
  profiles: office
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: office
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      office: http://office:8761/eureka/
      shahbour: http://shahbour:8761/eureka/
---
spring:
  profiles: shahbour
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: shahbour
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      office: http://office:8761/eureka/
      shahbour: http://shahbour:8761/eureka/
```

and for the services

```
eureka:
  client:
    preferSameZoneEureka: true
    region: lebanon
    serviceUrl:
      office: http://office:8761/eureka/
      shahbour: http://shahbour:8761/eureka/
    availabilityZones:
      lebanon: office,shahbour
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${server.port}}}
      zone: office
hystrix:
  command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000

---
spring:
  profiles: shahbour
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: shahbour
  client:
    availabilityZones:
      lebanon: shahbour,office
```

by doing so , i am able to use any service on the office zone but as soon i start that service on my own environment (zone) i start using it.